# Jboss AS7 to Wildfly 10 Migration

Tags: jboss, jboss-cli

im trying to migrate JBoss AS7.1 to Wildfly 10, i just followed some threads and i came upon this [AS7 to Wildfly 10](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+AS7+to+WildFly) guide. Basically it just tells how to migrate server configuration as well as application configuration.

But the problem is, it says to execute "`:migrate`" function "`/subsystem=jacorb:migrate`" on jboss cli (Jboss AS7.1 because it says execute on legacy subsystem) but it always throws an error, see below

```
No handler for migrate at address
```

Anyone familiar in executing migrate on jboss cli please point me to the right direction

**UPDATES**

I opted to migrate to wildfly10 from jboss-as7.1 manually (labor intensive, hassle), maybe if i have time to investigate about this i could feedback it there but as of know i time is of the essence and i need to migrate immediately.

Comment: Are you migrating to WildFly 10.1.0.Final?

Comment: yes, please note from Jboss AS7 to Wildfly 10.. the migration tool on wildlfy only supports EAP versions of JBoss

Comment: I tried locally and it seemed to work. Are you booting the with the standalone.xml from WildFly or JBoss AS 7.1?

Comment: was running wildfly 10, with standalone.xml from JBoss AS

Comment: Hmm... ...in my simple test that worked on WildFly 10.1.0.Final.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins on my end, it throws the error (stated above). anyways we opted to construct wildfly10 from jboss-as 7.1 from ground up (manual migration). very tedious and waste of time (for me).